# Android NDK Build failing in mac system but works in windows system

Tags: macos, android-ndk, eclipse-adt

1. added NDK path through ADT’s Preference
2. add native support through Android tools

I tried searching the internet But I couldn’t find anything useful to solve my problem

It compiles so many c,cpp files for 1 mins then suddently the following error comes up

```
make: /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/crypto/cryptlib.o] Error 127


<terminated> NDKBuilder [program] /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/Android-ndk-r10/ndk-build.cmd

NDKBuilder [program] /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/Android-ndk-r10/ndk-build.cmd :                                                                                                         
line 1: @echo: command not found
NDKBuilder [program] /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/Android-ndk-r10/ndk-build.cmd : 
line 2: rem: command not found
NDKBuilder [program] /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/Android-ndk-r10/ndk-build.cmd : 
line 3: call : command not found
NDKBuilder [program] /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/Android-ndk-r10/ndk-build.cmd : 
line 4: Syntax error near unexpected token ‘(‘
NDKBuilder [program] /Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/Android-ndk-r10/ndk-build.cmd : 
line 5:’If ERRORLEVEL 1 (exit /b 1)’
```

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see you're using NDK r10, but your app is asking for the gcc 4.4.3 toolchain that is not available since at least r9.

You can check for `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` variable inside a *Application.mk* file, and remove it so it uses the default toolchain that is available (4.6).

Another issue is that ndk-build.cmd is called. But `ndk-build.cmd` is to be used on Windows, not on Mac or Linux where `ndk-build` should be used instead.

You can check if a "build command" is manually set to it inside the eclipse C/C++ properties of your project.

Comment: one upvote for the answer But its not working for me.It seems like I have some compatibility problem with my source code As the error is big I have posted it on my blog http://shajotechblog.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/ndkr10-and-openvpn-error/

Comment: The errors you get seems to indicate that your NDK can't link to OpenSSL libraries, maybe you're missing some OpenSSL prebuilts for the architectures you're targeting.
Are you using the ndk r10 for 64-bit targets ?
Inside *Application.mk*, change `APP_ABI:=all` to `APP_ABI:=all32` to compile only for 32-bit architectures.

Comment: Your answers are really highly fruitful I will try